# Sbt: compile using Java 6 and run using Java 7

Tags: scala, jvm, sbt

I have a Scala 2.10.3 project that uses Swing. I have the following catch-22 situation:

- I must compile against Java 6 because of a bug with Scala Swing not working with Java 7
- I must run the project with Java 7 because OpenJDK 6 on Linux is broken (crashes with various Swing components)

I can compile with

```
$ sbt -java-home /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/ test:products
```

But when I try to run:

```
$ sbt run
```

`sbt` figures that the JVM version changes, and tries to recompile everything, thus throwing a compile error due to the first problem.

How can I convince `sbt` to run my project that was already compiled, although using a different JVM? Using `assembly` is not an option, because that takes several minutes, and I need to do this a lot.

---

I also tried to switch using `export JAVA_HOME`, but this has the same effect, sbt will try to recompile upon `run`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`javaHome` key](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking.html#java-home), scoped to the `run` task, to control the JDK used when running.

Assuming you run SBT with JDK6, as in:

```
sbt -java-home /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/
```

Add a custom location for `javaHome` in your `build.sbt`:

```
// no custom Java_HOME without forking
fork in run := true

// your JDK7 install
javaHome in run := Some(file("/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/"))
```

`compile` will then use JDK6, and `run` JDK7. You can also remove `in run` in the above definitions to have it apply to both `run` and `test`.

See  the [Forking](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Forking.html) section of the SBT documentation for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible possible solution: The project is developed with IntelliJ IDEA.

- IDEA runs on JDK 7 anyway
- Use the third party `sbt` plug-in for IDEA.
- In File -> Settings -> SBT (third party), locate "IDE Settings", check "Use alternative JRE" and select JDK 6 here.
- Now the project can be compiled with the integrated sbt console, since sbt is launched using JDK 6
- Run the project with a standard IDEA run configuration, using "Before launch: Run SBT Action 'test:products'". IDEA will launch the project using JDK 7